# How to fix Http public key pinning issue with a generic code

Tags: ssl, https, websecurity

I've added below section in my httpd conf file to support public key pinning for my website:

```
Header set Public-Key-Pins "pinsha256=\"my_public_keyhash_generatedfrom_mycertificate.crt\"; max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
```

Tomorrow if I change my certificate , I've to hard code the new public key here, how can I use a generic code snippet for Http public key pinning for various domain and various environment.

Comment: What is a generic code snippet in that context? By definition, each time you change your key (not necessarily each time you change your certificate, you can renew certificates using same key) you will need to change your header. Note that for multiple reasons, browsers are not in love anymore with HPKP so you might need to assess if you really need to use it or not.

Comment: Thanks for this update. So each time if I'm changing the certificate I've to update the public hash accordingly and there's no way around to this.

Comment: That is not true: again, you can renew a certificate without changing the public key it is based on. See `--reuse-key` option in `certbot` for example.